# Imagem em listview com SqlLite / Drawable

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, drawable

Tenho um App que efetua uma busca em telefones de empresas em um banco de dados SQLLite, .
Está funcionando normalmente, mas preciso inserir imagem em algumas dessas empresas.
O campo do banco de dados estaria somente o nome da imagem e a imagem estaria na pasta res/drawable...
Não vou utilizar campo blob.
Como faço pra mostrar essa imagem em imageview no meu listview de resultados. Veja meu código abaixo

```
String mostraTexto = params.getString("palavrachave");  // parametro para busca

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select nome,liberado,imagem,cidade,CIDADES._id,telefone,ddd,tipo,cid_nome,TELEFONES._id from TELEFONES INNER JOIN CIDADES ON TELEFONES.cidade = CIDADES._id where telefone like '%" + mostraTexto + "%' or nome like '%" + mostraTexto + "%' order by cid_nome,nome", null);


    String[] from = {"nome","telefone","cid_nome","ddd"};
    int[] to = {R.id.txt_nome, R.id.txt_telefone, R.id.txt_cidade, R.id.txt_ddd, R.dr};

    //vamos contas os resultados
    int id[]=new int[cursor.getCount()];
    if (cursor.getCount() < 1)
    {           
     AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(Resultado.this);
     dialogo.setTitle("Aviso");
     dialogo.setMessage("Nenhuma resultado na sua pesquisa!");
     dialogo.setNeutralButton("Ok", null);
     dialogo.show();
    }
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) 
    {

    android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter ad =
            new android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    getBaseContext(),R.layout.buscar_ltw,cursor, from, to, 0);

    ListView ltw_listar = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ltw_listar);

        ltw_listar.setAdapter(ad);
```

Comment: O nome da imagem é o id do recurso ou o "filename"? Não poderia guardar no banco o id ou a URI com o caminho absoluto? Porque o SimpleCursorAdapter trata o valor da coluna como o id do drawable nesse pasta e ou a URI.

Comment: Wakim
Recuperar o ID da imagem eu consigo tranquilamente. Só não estou conseguindo enviar para o campo ImageView presente no ListWiew.
Analise o meu código, onde eu poderia e como colocar o comando para enviar a imagem para o imageView.

Answer (score 1):

use esse trecho para pegar o id da imagem

```
   String mDrawableName = "myImageName";
int id = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
```

e para setar a image é assim

```
imageview.setImageResource(id);
```